# Show the range of a fuction is $(-2,2)$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

Please help me to solve "show the range of $$h=\frac{-2k}{\sqrt{1+k^{2}}}$$ is $(-2,2)$", thanks!

Limit can not be used here!

Comment: Are you allowed to take limits?

Comment: No,that's the problem

Comment: You should include in your post then what you are not allowed to use, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: Ok,thanks for mention

Answer (score 2):

$$h = \frac{-2k}{\sqrt{1+k^2}} \\ \implies h\sqrt{1+k^2} = -2k \\ \implies h^2(1+k^2)=4k^2 \\ \implies h^2+k^2h^2-4k^2=0 \\ \implies k^2(h^2-4)=-h^2 \\ \implies k^2=\frac{-h^2}{h^2-4} \\ \implies k^2=\frac{-h^2}{(h+2)(h-2)}  $$ Now observe that plugging in $h= \pm2$ results in division by zero, so $h \neq \pm 2$. Now if $h>2$ we can see that the RHS will always be negative. This is impossible because the LHS has to be positive, so $h<2$ only. But, if $h<-2$ then we run in to the exact same problem, so $h>-2$. Thus, we conclude $h \in (-2,2)$.

Comment: It looks like the inverse function, if it is, then by the definition of inverse, should I think about the bijection?

Comment: It is not the inverse. the equation is in terms of $k^2$, not $k$

Comment: Alright, thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, although RossMillikan said it before I could Latex it :)

Comment: I have to show that R(h)⊆(-2,2) and (-2,2)⊆R(h),how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

One approach:  Think about what happens when $k$ is large in absolute value. What does it approach as $k \to \pm \infty$?

Another:  Solve for $k$ in terms of $h$.  Start by squaring, then solve for $k^2$  Show that if $h$ is outside the range, disaster happens, while if $h$ is in that range you get a sensible solution.  You need to justify that the solution (one of them) is not extraneous and introduced by the squaring.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forget to mention that limit can not be used, and it's about image I think? Is there any other idea to me, thanks for your help!

Comment: graydad implements my second suggestion, which does not involve limits.

Comment: I have to show that R(h)⊆(-2,2) and (-2,2)⊆R(h),how can I do this?

Comment: graydad has shown you how.  He gives an explicit computation that, given an $h \in (-2,2)$, provides two $k$s that will correspond to that $h$.

Comment: He shows R(h)⊆(-2,2),but he didn't show (-2,2)⊆R(h),how can I show the second part?

Comment: By observing that you can solve this for any value of $h$ in that range.  Outside that range $k^2$ is negative.  You have to worry about whether you have introduced an extraneous solution in the squaring step and in fact you have-$k$ has to have the opposite sign of $h$, but one of the solutions is still good.

Answer (score 0):

$$h^2=\frac{4k^2}{k^2+1}\iff h^2-4=\frac{4k^2}{k^2+1}-4=4-\frac4{k^2+1}\le4$$

or set $k=\tan\theta$ to find $h=-2\sin\theta$

Comment: I have to show that R(h)⊆(-2,2) and (-2,2)⊆R(h),how can I do this?

Comment: @user133140, $$a^2\le4\iff-2\le a\le2$$ OR for real $\theta,$ $$-1\le\sin\theta\le1\iff-1\le-\sin\theta\le1$$